# Flutter - preview file

Tags: flutter, file, preview

i would like to upload file in a flutter app.
When I obtain io.file, i would like to display a preview / thumbnail (for example, the first page of a word or pdf file ; first sheet of an excel file ...)

My question doesn't concern images

Thx